# How do I RP a ranger obtaining a beast companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

How exactly does a ranger befriend a beast companion and how should I introduce one when they reach the level where they get one?

Comment: This seems pretty subjective... There are any number of ways you could RP it, and no defined way. ...And yeah, definitely seems like a duplicate of the question @Sdjz linked.

Comment: Swipe right on his "Tinder" box? Kidding aside, this seems very opinion based.

Comment: 1. Make it a spirit vision quest (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsFCdepLPSc) <<or>>

2. Concentrate for 8 hours, which will turn you into an animal beacon, which will attract the animal you want.

Comment: Go on a-ranging through the woodlands, meet an injured bear, a sick owl, or a trapped wolf. Lovingly bind its wounds/free it, cast a quick cure-light-wounds, and BFF!